# Regex lookbehind ignoring whitespace character

Tags: regex

I would like to show you my approach for an issue I'm having, and maybe you can help me with the particular problem or even changing the approach.

I have some log lines like this, take this two for example:

```
00:00:02.673: INFO: sesison1::logging : logSessionStarted(ch...")
EntrySuccessfull::execute
```

As you can see there are some with timestamp or some not, the issue is that I want to take all the data before the first ocurrence '::'.

Now with the second case its easy, something like this works:

```
(.*)(?=::)
```

Returns for all the dataset:

```
00:00:02.673: INFO: sesison1
EntrySuccessfull
```

Obviously for the first row it's not like I'd like it. I would like to get sesision1, so I tried to make something like a lookbehind until a whitespace is found:

```
(?<=\s)(.*)(?=::)
```

So finally, I could do something like find '::' and go back until white space or begining of the string, but this second change returns the very same results, like its ignoring the white space before sesision1.

is there any better approach or something wrong?

**PD all the tests done with notepad++**

Comment: Replace `.*` with `\S*`. `\S+(?=::)` will do.

Comment: Or, a safer version to get all before the first `::` only after a whitespace / start of line: `(?<!\S)[^\s:]\S*?(?=::)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\b` matches word boundaries so you could use `\b\S+(?=::)`

This starts at a word boundary and matches multiple non-whitespace characters until it gets to `::`

Comment: This works! I just ran into a new issue that maybe you can help. For the line                        "static void NewSer::MultiValueCallback::doCallbacks(std::set& - Absor)" I would need Just NewSer, but this expresion returns alll until set &.  Is it possible to combine in one expression this new condition with the one you offered?

Comment: If you're happy to exclude all `:` from the match then this would work `\b[^:\s]+(?=::)`. It will match "NewSer" but also "MultiValueCallback" etc. but I presume you can just take the first match.
If the line is "example:line::" then it will match just "line"

Comment: Actually a better adjustment to make is to make the quantifier lazy. `\b\S+?(?=::)`. This means that it will stop the first time it finds `::`. https://regex101.com/r/PzsQfS/1

Comment: thank you very much, this did exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

With `(\S+)(?=::)` you can get both matches without null-matches. Please check [here](https://regex101.com/r/5ZyksT/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have one issue with the example you propose, what if I still wanted only to ::MORE(the first match off the token '::' and then left until whitespace or start of sentence)?

Comment: @AlejandroA Haven't you accepted a solution that works for you? Anyway, I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes but I ran into a new issue, I will work a little bit more by myself and if not open a new question, thanks.